# How to stop billing of deleted instance of AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I deleted my AWS DB instances(mysql) but still DB billing increasing, I'm not getting how it's happening, but daily it's increasing bill.
can anyone help to stop my DB billing.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely something is still around which is costing you money.  Do you have any backups there?  Are you certain that all instances are really gone?  Maybe some other service is silently spinning up a new RDS instance in the background.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I'm not getting about backup or other background service running, here  snapshort  creating automatic and it's not deleting too.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the billing details from your Billing Dashboard, under "Bill Details".